# Deep clone a class object with object methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

How do I deep clone an object of a user-defined class and also keep the object methods of the class?

For example, I have a Object class called `Schedule` with member `days: number[]` and function `getWeekdays()`

So if I want to make a new `Schedule` object which would be a clone of an existing `Schedule` with cloned properties and also to have the `getWeekdays()` function how would I do that? I tried `Object.assign()` but that only shallow-copies `days` and I know `JSON.parse()` won't work because I won't get the object methods. I tried lodash's `_.cloneDeep()` but unfortunately the object that creates is missing the object methods.

Comment: What if you just add a copy constructor and recreate the instance that way? Oh, you only have a type... well, what if you create a class for your object?

Comment: @pushkin Sorry, `Schedule` is actually a class -- I'll fix the question. But yes I guess I could use a copy constructor but a generalized solution would be nicer if possible

Answer (score 5):

`Object.assign()` will keep the `getWeekdays()` method if you bind the method to the object instead of its prototype with one of the following approaches:

> ⚠️ *Binding methods directly to an object instead of its prototype is generally considered an antipattern- especially in cases where performance is a higher priority- since N `Schedule`s would reference N **seperate** `getWeekend()` functions instead of referencing the single `getWeekend()` function that would otherwise be shared by the prototype.*

---

### Arrow function methods

The first approach is to declare your method in the `class` definition using an arrow function, like so:

```
class Schedule {
  public days: Array<number> = [];

  public getWeekdays = (): Array<number> => {
    return this.days;
  }
}

const clone = Object.assign({}, new Schedule());
```

#### ...but why?

The reason this works is twofold:

- because the arrow function syntax binds the method to the resulting object instead of its prototype.
- because `Object.assign()` copies an object's own properties but not its inherited properties.

If you run `console.log(new Schedule());` you can see the first point in action:

```
// with arrow function:
▼ Schedule {days: Array(0), getWeekdays: } ⓘ
  ▷ days: Array(0) []
  ▷ getWeekdays: () => { … }
  ▷ __proto__: Object { constructor: … }


// without arrow function:
▼ Schedule { days: Array(0) } ⓘ
  ▷ days: Array(0) []
  ▼ __proto__: Object { constructor: , getWeekdays: }
    ▷ constructor: class Schedule { … }
    ▷ getWeekdays: getWeekdays() { … }
    ▷ __proto__: Object { constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , … }
```

#### How does this differ from a `static` method?

A `static` method is bound not the the object's prototype, but to the `class` itself, which is the prototype's constructor:

```
class Schedule {
  public static days: Array<number> = [];

  public static getWeekdays(): Array<number> {
    return this.days;
  }
}

const clone = Object.assign({}, new Schedule());
console.log(new Schedule());

// console
▼ Schedule {} ⓘ
  ▼ __proto__: Object { constructor: … }
    ▼ constructor: class Schedule { … }
        [[FunctionLocation]]: internal#location
      ▷ [[Scopes]]: Scopes[1]
        arguments: …
        caller: …
      ▷ days: Array(0) []
      ▷ getWeekdays: getWeekdays() { … }
        length: 0
        name: "Schedule"
      ▷ prototype: Object { constructor: … }
      ▷ __proto__: function () { … }
    ▷ __proto__: Object { constructor: … , __defineGetter__: … , __defineSetter__: … , … }
```

This means that a `static` method may not be bound directly to an object. If you try, you'll get this TSError:

```
~/dev/tmp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:261
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
index.ts(14,14): error TS2334: 'this' cannot be referenced in a static property initializer.

at createTSError (~/dev/tmp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:261:12)
at getOutput (~/dev/tmp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:367:40)
at Object.compile (~/dev/tmp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:558:11)
at Module._compile (~/dev/tmp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:43)
at internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10
at Object..ts (~/dev/tmp/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
at Function._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
at Function.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:12)
```

---

### `.bind()` in the constructor

Arrow functions (including those used in `class` method definitions) are an ES6 feature which provide a more concise syntax to function declaration expressions in regards to the behavior of the `this` keyword. Unlike regular functions, arrow functions use the `this` value of their enclosing lexical scope rather than establishing their own `this` value based on the context of their invocation. They also do not receive their own `arguments` object (or `super`, or `new.target`).

Prior to ES6, if you needed to use `this` in a method being used as a callback, you'd have to bind the host object's value of `this` to the method's value of `this` with `.bind()`, which returns an updated function with its `this` value set to the provided value, like so:

```
var clone;

function Schedule() {
  this.days = [];

  this.setWeekdays = function(days) {
    this.days = days;
  }

  this.setWeekdays = this.setWeekdays.bind(this);
}

clone = Object.assign({}, new Schedule());
console.log(clone);

// console
▼ Object {days: Array(0), setWeekdays: }
  ▷ days:Array(0) []
  ▷ setWeekdays:function () { … }
  ▷ __proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}
```

In an ES6 `class`, you can achieve the same results by calling `.bind()` on the method in the constructor:

```
class Schedule {
  public days: Array<number> = [];

  constructor() {
    this.getWeekdays = this.getWeekdays.bind(this);
  }

  public getWeekdays(): Array<number> {
    return this.days;
  }
}

const clone = Object.assign({}, new Schedule());
console.log(clone);

// console
▼ Object {days: Array(0), setWeekdays: … } ⓘ
  ▷ days: Array(0) []
  ▷ setWeekdays: function () { … }
  ▷ __proto__: Object { constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , … }
```

---

### Future Bonus: Autobind Decorators

> ⚠️ *Also not necessarily recommended since you end up allocating functions which are usually never called, as explained below.*

Decorators are considered an experimental feature in TypeScript and require that you set `experimentalDecorators` to `true` explicitly in your `tsconfig.json`.

Using an autobind decorator would allow you to rebind the `getWeekdays()` method "on demand"- just like using the `.bind()` key in the constructor but the binding occurs when `getWeekdays()` is invoked instead of when `new Schedule()` is called- only in a more compact way:

```
class Schedule {
  public days: Array<number> = [];

  @bound
  public getWeekdays(): Array<number> {
    return this.days;
  }
}
```

However, because Decorators are still in Stage 2, enabling decorators in TypeScript only exposes interfaces for the 4 types of decorator functions (i.e. `ClassDecorator`, `PropertyDecorator`, `MethodDecorator`, `ParameterDecorator`.) The built-in decorators proposed in Stage 2, including [`@bound`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#bound), are not included out of the box.

In order to use `@bound`, you'll have to let Babel handle your TypeScript transpilation with [`@babel/preset-typescript`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript) along with [`@babel/preset-stage-2`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-2).

Alternatively, this functionality can be (somewhat) polyfilled with this NPM package:

- [autobind-decorator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autobind-decorator)

This package's `@boundMethod` will bind the `getWeekdays()` method to the resulting object of `new Schedule()` *in addition* to its prototype but will **not** be copied by `Object.assign()`:

```
// console.log(new Schedule());
▼ Schedule { days: Array(0) } ⓘ
  ▷ days: Array(0) []
  ▷ getWeekdays: function () { … }
  ▼ __proto__: Object { constructor: , getWeekdays: <accessor> }
    ▷ constructor: class Schedule { … }
    ▷ getWeekdays: getWeekdays() { … }
    ▷ __proto__: Object { constructor: … , __defineGetter__: … , __defineSetter__: … , … }

// console.log(clone);
▼ Object { days: Array(0) } ⓘ
  ▷ days: Array(0) []
  ▷ __proto__: Object { constructor: … , __defineGetter__: … , __defineSetter__: … , … }
```

This is because the `@boundMethod` decorator overrides the method's `get` and `set` accessors to call `.bind()` (since the value of `this` in these accessors is set to the object through which the property is assigned), attach it to the object with `Object.defineProperty()`, then return the `PropertyDescriptor` for the bound method, which has some interesting effects:

```
const instance = new Schedule();

console.log('instance:', instance);
console.log('\ninstance.hasOwnProperty(\'getWeekdays\'):', instance.hasOwnProperty('getWeekdays'));
console.log('\ninstance.getWeekdays():', instance.getWeekdays());
console.log('\ninstance.hasOwnProperty(\'getWeekdays\'):', instance.hasOwnProperty('getWeekdays'));

// console
instance: 
▼ Schedule { days: Array(0) } ⓘ
  ▷ days: Array(0) []
  ▷ getWeekdays: function () { … }
  ▷ __proto__: Object { constructor: , getWeekdays: <accessor> }

instance.hasOwnProperty('getWeekdays'): false

instance.getWeekdays():
▷ Array(0) []

instance.hasOwnProperty('getWeekdays'): true
```

The reason `Object.assign()` won't work is actually twofold:

- it actually *invokes* `[[Get]]` on the source object (i.e. `new Schedule()`) and `[[Set]]` on the target object (i.e. `{}`).
- the `PropertyDescriptor`s that `@boundMethod` uses to overhaul `getWeekend()`s accessors are not enumerable.

If we were to change that last point and use enumerable accessors, we could get `Object.assign()` to work, but only *after* `getWeekdays()` has already been invoked at least once:

```
const instance = new Schedule();
const clone1 = Object.assign({}, instance);

void instance.getWeekdays();

const clone2 = Object.assign({}, instance);

console.log('clone1:', clone1);
console.log('clone2:', clone2);

// console
clone1: 
▼ Object { days: Array(0) } ⓘ
  ▷ days: Array(0) []
  ▷ __proto__: Object { constructor: … , __defineGetter__: … , __defineSetter__: … , … }

clone2: 
▼ Object { days: Array(0) } ⓘ
  ▷ days: Array(0) []
  ▷ getWeekdays: function () { … }
  ▷ __proto__: Object { constructor: … , __defineGetter__: … , __defineSetter__: … , … }
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that should the arrow function refer to any properties of the object, they will be those of the original object and NOT those on the clone.
So, if your cloned object has a value updated then the new value will not be used in the execution of the function

Answer (score 1):

Try the `copy` function from [here](https://www.codementor.io/avijitgupta/deep-copying-in-js-7x6q8vh5d)

```js
// from https://www.codementor.io/avijitgupta/deep-copying-in-js-7x6q8vh5d
function copy(o) {
   var output, v, key;
   output = Array.isArray(o) ? [] : {};
   for (key in o) {
       v = o[key];
       output[key] = (typeof v === "object") ? copy(v) : v;
   }
   return output;
}


var Event = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Event(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    Event.prototype.getName = function () {
        return "Event " + this.name;
    };
    return Event;
}());
var Schedule = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Schedule() {
    }
    Schedule.prototype.getWeekdays = function () {
        return this.weekDays;
    };
    return Schedule;
}());
var schedule = new Schedule();
schedule.days = [3, 11, 19];
schedule.weekDays = [1, 2, 3];
schedule.event = new Event("Event");

var clone = copy(schedule);
console.log(clone);
```

Comment: OP's using Typescript. You might as well just use the standard `class` syntax

Comment: I'm confused since the source you referenced also claims that `var b = Object.assign({}, a);` worked but when I use `Object.assign(new Schedule(), originalSchedule)` I get a shallow copy??

Comment: @KyleV. `Object.assign({}, a)` will not be useful for you, because the cloned object will not keep the `getWeekdays()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first serialize the object into JSON, make a deep clone of the result, and then deserialize it back into the class object. You can use a library such as this: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

So in the end it would look like this:

```
import { classToPlain, plainToClass } from "class-transformer";

let a = new Schedule();
let aSerialized = classToPlain(a);
let b = plainToClass(Schedule, aSerialized);
```

Or you can use the `classToClass` method:

```
import { classToClass } from "class-transformer";
let b = classToClass(a);
```

The gotcha is that you have to annotate the class with some annotations from the above library, but I don't think there's a better way to do it.